# I need to create a Perl 5 regex statement that will parse 2 separate dates from a string

Tags: regex, perl, date, parsing

The string is of the following format:
"Unwanted words and spaces"  Date1  "and" Date2.  Date 2 is at the very end of the whole string.  How can I go about writing this?  The date formats are of the form m/dd/yyyy.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please provide your attempts and realistic input strings. A simple [**`\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}`**](https://regex101.com/r/Tar2zZ/1) will probably do.

Comment: ...but don't forget to escape the slashes: `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}`. (Assuming your regex is delimited by slashes.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where you dump your requirements and get people to do your work for you. What have you tried so far? Show your work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your strings are simple enough and follow your format exactly the following will work:

```
my $string = "Unwanted words and spaces 3/10/2012 and 12/15/1980\n";
my ($dt1,$dt2) = $string=~ m|\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}|g;
say $dt1 . ' ' . $dt2;
```

output:

`3/10/2012 12/15/1980`

Comment: I guess I assumed you could have 2 digit months although you only indicated one digit: m/dd/yyyy

Comment: No, this is exactly what I was looking for and is very straightforward.  I thought my requirements were pretty clear and based on your response, I can see that you understood perfectly.  The syntax I was using was MUCH too complex, which is probably what lead to my deepening confusion as I continued to make attempts at it.  Thanks for your help, cbmckay!

Comment: Cool. Could you accept this answer?

Comment: Yep, sorry for the delay.  I don't come here often.  : )